# repeat insert value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```html
<?php
include("config.php");
$cart=$_GET['cart'];
$numberofcart=$_GET['numberofcart'];
if ($cart) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO trade (cart,price) values('$cart','150LE')");

}
?>


<form action="index.php" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="cart" />
  <input type="text" name="numberofcart" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

number of cart = number of repeat

iwant like this in mysql
    id  cart    price
    1   pen     150LE
    2   pen     150LE
    3   pen     150LE

Comment: stop using `mysql_*`. use `mysqli_*`  or `PDO`

Comment: And learn [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As for your question, use a loop

Comment: example for me pls

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, the [official documentation has plenty of examples of loops](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$cart=$_POST['cart'];
$numberofcart=$_POST['numberofcart'];
$values ='';

if ($cart !=='' && $numberofcart !=='') {
    for($i=0;$i<$numberofcart;$i++){
        $values .= "('$cart','150LE'),";
    }
    $values = trim($values,',');
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO trade (cart,price) values $values");// good to change connection code in file according to mysqli_* standards
}else{
    echo "form field are required";
}
?>


<form action="index.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="cart" />
  <input type="text" name="numberofcart" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Example:-https://eval.in/694166